# Strong convexity of the convex conjugate

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I'm trying to understand the strong convexity of the convex conjugate defined on a Banach space. Assume $B$ is a Banach space with the norm $||\cdot||_{B}$. Consider a smooth (wrt $||\cdot||_B$) function $\phi: B \to \mathbb{R}$ and denote its convex conjugate by $\phi^*: B^* \to \mathbb{R}$.

For finite-dimensional Banach spaces, it has been established that if $\phi$ is smooth then $\phi^*$ is strongly convex (wrt $||\cdot||_{B^*}$) (cf https://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.0813.pdf by Anatoli B. Juditsky and Arkadi S.Nemirovski). I'm trying to understand if this property holds for $\phi$ defined on a general Banach space $B$ (e.g. infinite dimensional Banach spaces).

Comment: Please give the definition of "smooth" and "strongly convex". In a Banach space, several definitions are floating around (at least in my head)...

Comment: Now sure if the cited paper uses completely unusual definitions of these notions. But using standard definitions the assertions seems wrong: Take $\phi$ identical to 0. Then $\phi$ is smooth and convex. And $\phi^*$ is 0 as well and hence convex. But it is not strongly convex.